# How can I delete tables marked 'in use' using phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

As in title. When I try to drop these tables I see something like this:

1051: Unknown table 'urls_count'

Tables are marked as 'in use':

[image: screenshot of the problem]

I have checked that no application is using these table, as this is new database on my server and is not connected anywhere. Also there are no dependencies between these tables. I tried to repair these tables, optimize them, check them, and whatever actions I can run, even if it seems bit awkward, but I still cant get rid of them.

How can I delete them?

---

**Web server configuration:**

cpsrvd 11.32.2.28, MySQL client version: 5.0.95, PHP extension: mysql

**MySQL configuration:**

Server: Localhost via UNIX socket,
Server version: 5.0.95-community,
Protocol version: 10,
MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

**PHPmyadmin version:** 3.4.10.1

Comment: Just edited my question, and provided these details

Comment: This might be a case that you r performing any join type operations between different set of collation table that results in these type of tables. Try by ensuring that all the tables and their corresponding columns have the same character set and collation.

Comment: I know your comment is old *"This might be a case that you r performing any join type operations between different set of collation table that results in these type of tables."* @swapnesh No that cant happen.. MySQL wouldn't change the source tables data/collation when implicit collation convertion is happing when compatible collations can be converted like ascii/latin1 to utf8 on runtime or a explicit collation with (`COLLATE <collate>`)

Comment: @RaymondNijland I am not sure with the behaviour now with the current phpmyadmin/mysql... but to my best of believe I think that I might have encountered this scenario at that time and only on that basis I made this comment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have shell access, try this;

cd /var/lib/mysql/DATABASE  (where DATABASE is the one you're trying to fix)

myisamchk --safe-recover TABLE  (where TABLE is the table you are tring to fix)

This will will repair the table in safemode, and SHOULD result in success.

Comment: I have just checked, I don't have shell access... I will contact support and will see whether they can enable it.

Comment: It seems this solution worked out. Another possible solution is export tables you want to save, and simply delete and re-create database.